# How to project coordinates in spatialite using PHP?

Tags: coordinate-system, spatialite, php, intersect, identify

I'm using a spatialite database in a PHP program and I need to simulate an "identify" on a polygon layer (EPSG 32632), using point whose coordinates are dinamically generated.

I know that this query works fine ...

```
select NAME from poly32632 where within(GeomFromText('POINT(837121 5087604)'),poly32632.Geometry);
```

My problem is that my points coordinates are originally in EPSG 4326 system coordinates so, I've to project them in EPSG 32632 before to use them in my select.

I don't use Javascript in my program, so I can't use something like PROJ4JS to do it: is it possible to convert my coordinates couple directly in EPSG 32632 in my Spatialite query construction? Alternative queries in Spatialite to obtain the same result?

Comment: Find ST_Transform from https://www.gaia-gis.it/gaia-sins/spatialite-sql-latest.html. Then you feed in EPSG:4326 coordinates and convert them on-the-fly into EPSG:32632 `ST_Transform(GeomFromText('POINT(13.342886 45.859404)',4326),32632)`